# Minification disrupts SVG to Image transformation

Tags: angularjs, svg, minify

In my angular app I transform an SVG to an Image using canvg. Before applying canvg I attach style rules to the serialized svg string. See code:

```
      var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg");
      var svgClone = svg[0].cloneNode(true);

      var viewbox = svgClone.getAttribute( 'viewBox' ).split( ' ' )


      var width = 2*viewbox[2] - viewbox[0];
      var height = 2*viewbox[3] - viewbox[1];


      svgClone.setAttribute("width",  width);
      svgClone.setAttribute("height", height);

      console.log(svgClone)
      var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
      var svgString;
      var canvas = document.getElementById("empty-canvas");
      var str;
      var styleTag;

      var style = "\n";

      for (var i = 1; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {

        str = document.styleSheets[i].href.split("/");

        if (str[str.length - 1] == "svg.css") {
          var rules = document.styleSheets[i].rules;
          if (!rules) {
            var rules = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules; //firefox
          };
          for (var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
            style += (rules[j].cssText + "\n");
          }
          break;
        }
      }
      styleTag = "<style type='text/css'>" + style + "</style>";
      $(svgClone).prepend(styleTag);
      svgString = serializer.serializeToString(svgClone);

      canvg(canvas, svgString, {

        renderCallback: function() {
          var pngImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
          $scope.image = pngImage;
        }
      });
```

This works fine in development mode. However when I minify all js files for production mode this code does not seem to work anymore because the resulting images lack styling (some colors, font-size etc.).

I'm pretty sure the problem is that the minified code is not prepending the style tag but I am not sure how to solve it.

Any hints are appreciated
Jean

Comment: presumably the problem is in the minification process which you have not described in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was an issue with the file that is being specified